# fs write audio stream to pcm creates empty file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
          file = 'bop.pcm'
          const strm = fs.createWriteStream(file);
          let audioStream = receiver.createStream(user);
          audioStream.pipe(strm);
          audioStream.on('end', () => {
            strm.end()
          });
```

I'm using `discord.js` to record a voice channel. Voice recording code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/raw/7WViZw2z

It is creating empty file and there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of figuring trying to figure out why this won't work, I finally found a solution (not elegant but it works!!)

Basically, Discordjs doesn't let you read audio unless you (the bot) have played audio first. so what you need to do is play any short audio file. You can even set the volume to 0 if you don't want to actually hear the sound.

It will look something like this:

```
const dispatcher = connection.play('beep.mp3', {
  volume: 0
});

dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
  // put your code here
});
```

Once the 'finish' callback is called, you can run the code that you have.

Feel free to let me know if this works for you.
I don't know any other way to bypass this issue. If anyone else knows do let me know. Thanks.